# Importing a .dll library in python using eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse, dllimport

I'm fairly new to Python and I'm trying to use ctypes to use a .dll library

It comes out with error " winerror 193 1 is not a valid win32 application"

This is the c code that I use to create the .dll

```
__declspec(dllexport) int sum(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}
```

and this is the python code where I'm trying to import the dll

```
from ctypes import cdll

mydll = cdll.LoadLibrary('libTest.dll')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pass
```

It's fairly simple, but when I try to run it I get all this bunch of errors

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\robertodg\.p2\pool\plugins\org.python.pydev.core_6.4.3.201807050139\pysrc\_pydev_runfiles\pydev_runfiles.py", line 468, in __get_module_from_str
    mod = __import__(modname)
  File "C:\Users\robertodg\eclipse-workspace\LetsHope\Hope.py", line 8, in <module>
    mydll = cdll.LoadLibrary('libTest.dll')
  File "C:\Users\robertodg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 434, in LoadLibrary
    return self._dlltype(name)
  File "C:\Users\robertodg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 356, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid win32 application
```

I'm using eclipse on windows with the c and python prospective and I'm using and this is the python that I'm running
Python 3.7.0 (v3.7.0:1bf9cc5093, Jun 27 2018, 04:06:47) [MSC v.1914 32 bit (Intel)] on win32

I know that it's prob something really simple, but I've been banging my head for 2 days now.

thanks in advance

Comment: May be your dll's architecture doesn't match python'.(For example trying to load 64 bit dll using 32 bit python)

Comment: Yes, in the end I had to reinstall python 64 bit and that did the trick in this case.